# SSL Enable a SharePoint site on a port other than 443

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2013

There is a SharePoint web application on my server that is already https and listening on port 443 (which I don't own/administer). Currently, my SharePoint web application is http and on port 88. How do I SSL enable it on a different port other than 443? I think that if I create another SSL binding on 443, the other site or mine or both will become unusable, is that correct? What is the best approach for more than 1 SSL enabled SharePoint site on a web server? Can I do this via host headers, or dedicated IP Addresses and if yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this blog](http://www.harbar.net/articles/ssl.aspx). Either use different IP's or a wildcard certificate.

But if you are using SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012, then there is a new thing called SNI (New to IIS anyway) that allows you to use the hostname at the beginning of the handshake to identify the certificate to use.

To enable this all you have to do is go into IIS -> edit bindings, and check "Require Server Name Indication". This will switch the cert binding from IP:Port to Hostname:port, allowing for multiple web applications to use ssl with the same ip and port.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

And
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Also, you can ssl enable it on a port other than 443 by:

```
     Editing the bindings in IIS
     Then edit the AAM in Central Admin
```

You probably shouldn't do this though because your users will have to type the port after the websites name since it isn't using the 443 default.